# What does ExpressionVisitor.Visit<T> Do?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, expression-trees, expressionvisitor

Before someone shouts out the answer, please read the question through.

What is the purpose of the method in .NET 4.0's ExpressionVisitor:

```
public static ReadOnlyCollection<T> Visit<T>(ReadOnlyCollection<T> nodes, Func<T, T> elementVisitor)
```

My first guess as to the purpose of this method was that it would visit each node in each tree specified by the `nodes` parameter and rewrite the tree using the result of the `elementVisitor` function.

This does not appear to be the case. Actually this method appears to do a little more than nothing, unless I'm missing something here, which I strongly suspect I am...

I tried to use this method in my code and when things didn't work out as expected, I reflectored the method and found:

```
public static ReadOnlyCollection<T> Visit<T>(ReadOnlyCollection<T> nodes, Func<T, T> elementVisitor)
{
    T[] list = null;
    int index = 0;
    int count = nodes.Count;
    while (index < count)
    {
        T objA = elementVisitor(nodes[index]);
        if (list != null)
        {
            list[index] = objA;
        }
        else if (!object.ReferenceEquals(objA, nodes[index]))
        {
            list = new T[count];
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            {
                list[i] = nodes[i];
            }
            list[index] = objA;
        }
        index++;
    }
    if (list == null)
    {
        return nodes;
    }
    return new TrueReadOnlyCollection<T>(list);
}
```

So where would someone actually go about using this method? What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like a convenience method to apply an aribitrary transform function to an expression tree, and return the resulting transformed tree, or the original tree if there is no change.

I can't see how this is any different of a pattern that a standard expression visitor, other than except for using a visitor type, it uses a function.

As for usage:

```
Expression<Func<int, int, int>> addLambdaExpression= (a, b) => a + b;

// Change add to subtract
Func<Expression, Expression> changeToSubtract = e => 
{ 
    if (e is BinaryExpression) 
    { 
        return Expression.Subtract((e as BinaryExpression).Left,
                                   (e as BinaryExpression).Right); 
    }
    else
    {
        return e;
    }
};  

var nodes = new Expression[] { addLambdaExpression.Body }.ToList().AsReadOnly();
var subtractExpression = ExpressionVisitor.Visit(nodes, changeToSubtract);
```

You don't explain how you expected it to behave and why therefore you think it does little more than nothing.

Comment: I would have expected it to visit the entire tree in addLambdaExpression, not just addLambdaExpression itself.

Comment: In that case you'll want to inherit a custom type from ExpressionVisitor and handle the NodeType.Lambda in the Visit() method.

Comment: Any chance you know how to convert `subtractExpression` back to `Expression<Func<int, int, int>>`? I don't seem to find a complete example anywhere...